# Idempotent ideals having only idempotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, idempotents

I search for  sufficient conditions for a ring $R$ so that any idempotent ideal constitutes only of idempotent elements of $R$. Of course, in the commutative case, any finitely generated idempotent ideal is generated by an idempotent element.

Any internet searches in the relevant  literature (those in my hand) have come to naught. I would be appreciated, in advance, to any help or suggested information.

Comment: *"Of course, in the commutative case, any finitely generated idempotent ideal is generated by an idempotent element."* But what does that have to do with your question? There are finitely generated idempotent ideals in commutative rings which contain non-idempotent elements. Take any field other than $F_2$, for example. Or, if you prefer a nonfield, any finite product of fields other than $F_2$...

Comment: "Constitutes only of" literally means that *all* elements are idempotent. Did you mean "is generated by idempotent elements"? That would fit better with the comment about commutative rings and f.g. idempotent ideals...

Comment: Since $R$ itself is an ideal of $R$, your condition would mean that every element of $R$ is idempotent...

Comment: Yes, I mean that all elements of the ideal are idempotent. @rshwieb Yes, but I want to just state the mere result, no more. Any way, thanks for your examples. The idea of J.-E. Pin is a good one.

Comment: @karparvar Unfortunately the notification was typoed, so I didn't see this until now. If you are sticking with what's written, you're stuck with the class of Boolean rings in which all elements are idempotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand my comment into a slightly more complete answer.

Since $R$ itself is an ideal of $R$, the condition implies that every element of $R$ is idempotent and thus $R$ is a [Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring). Now every Boolean ring is commutative and defines a Boolean algebra where $x \wedge y = xy$ and $x \vee y = x + y + xy$ and $\bar x = 1 + x$. Conversely, every Boolean algebra $(B, \vee, \wedge, \overline{})$ defines a Boolean ring by setting $x + y =  (x ∨ y) ∧ \overline{(x ∧ y)}$ and $xy = x \wedge y$. Finally, [Stone's representation theorem for Boolean algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras) gives a complete characterisation of Boolean rings (or Boolean algebras) as a [fields of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets). A *fields of sets* is a Boolean subalgebra of the Boolean algebra $\mathcal{P}(E)$ of all subsets of a given set $E$, equipped with the operations $X \vee Y = X \cup Y$, $X \wedge Y = X \cap Y$ and $\overline{X} = E - X$, the complement of $X$).